# Will physics ever be able to answer the question: "What caused the universe to come into existance"?

Tags: thermodynamics, time, universe

Or is this just the flip side of a metaphysical question "why does the universe not exist", if the opposite was the case and nothing existed i.e. a universe devoid of all energy, matter forces, particles of any kind, massless or otherwise.

Comment: This belongs in philosophy, not physics. Voted to close.

Comment: If, by *Universe*, you mean *all* there is, was, and will be, the question "Why does the universe exist?" supposes a contradiction.

Comment: One should never start a question with "Why..." in science if it can't be formulated in a way that makes it start with "How...".

Comment: It is doubtful that there even is an answer to the question "Why does the universe exist?" The universe doesn't care about logic, or purpose. The universe simply is. Why can black holes form? Why do stars go supernova? There are, most likely, no answers to these questions. The universe does not need a reason to exist.

Comment: The late Dr. John Wheeler asked "How come existence?" And when asked if physicists might one day have a clear understanding of the origin of the universe Wheeler replied "absolutely". So, if "why" is replaced with "how", I think the question should be considered a legitimate one.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a belief that eventually we would discover/create a Theory of Everything (TOE) that would explain why all the constants have the value they have and why the universe and laws of physics could be no other way than they are.
I doubt whether anyone still believes that is possible.

Comment: On first read, your 'I doubt [...]' doesn't seem quite relevant. (However, perhaps you mean to understate.) Care to strengthen that last statement (perhaps using references/polls/etc. suggesting such a general stance/lack of belief/lack of ambition/whatever)?

Comment: It is merely that the best candidate, String Theory, does not offer a single solution but a multiverse of them. It may be we are here because we are here - anthropic selection